# automate downloading backup with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to automate downloading a backup. I can't seem to click the 'item_backup' link button.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="item" data-item-group="files" data-item-search-text="Backup restore Backup">
                            <a class="itemImageWrapper integrations_icon spriteicon_img icon-backup" id="icon-backup" href="backup/index.html"></a>
                            <a class="itemTextWrapper link" id="item_backup" href="backup/index.html">Backup</a>
                        </div>
```

And here's what I've got for the script. It opens and logs in but does not click the backup link.

```
$url = "https://www.com:2083";
$username="name";
$password="pass";
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
  { 
   Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000; 
   } 
$ie.Document.getElementById("user").value = $username; 
$ie.Document.getElementById("pass").value=$password;
$ie.Document.getElementById("login_submit").click();
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
  { 
   Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 9000; 
   } 
$ie.Document.getElementById("item_backup").click();
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct element and that element actually support the click event? This is really not  PowerShell issue, but what you are telling PowerShell to act upon. Since this appears to be your internal site, then it is impossible to see what is really there, thus forcing us to guess. As I am sure you already know, what you are doing is a very common thing.